# Composer could not find a composer.json file in /var/www/html

Tags: php, json, laravel, ubuntu, composer-php

I'm trying to set up an environment in my Virtual Machine which is an Ubuntu 15.10. I've followed a tutorial with these steps:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv ~/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

Then I do:

```
sudo nano ~/.profile
```

And I add this to end of file:

```
PATH="$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

Finally:

```
composer global update
```

After these steps, I try:

```
laravel new project
```

And get this error:

```
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/www/html/laravel_62a1f2f16d54929f3367e5f18f937a47.zip): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/alavaros/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php on line 114
PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::extractTo(): Permission denied in /home/alavaros/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php on line 132
PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::close(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object in /home/alavaros/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php on line 134
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /var/www/html
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
```

Comment: I recommend you use Laravel Homestead as a dev environment, it should come preconfigured with everything you need. https://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a permission issue.

What is the output of `ls -l /var/www`?
You should see that you have write permission (`w`) for public or that you are in the group listed.

For example, you might see

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jul  4  2015 .
```

Which means you would have issues writing to `/var/www` without acting as `root`.

Simply running `sudo laravel new project` might fix your current problem, but may incur you having to use `sudo` whenever you want to work.

A better solution would be to give yourself access to this directory:

```
sudo chmod o+w /var/www/
```

Running this command will give all (**o**ther) users (including you) on this machine **w**rite access to `/var/www`

Comment: Indeed it was a problem of permission, but I don't know why, I mean, I install LAMP, Composer and Laravel with the same user. What the way to install everything and not having this kind of problem? Thanks!!!

Comment: What commands did you use to install LAMP? Chances are you used a command like `sudo apt-get install apache mysql php`. The `sudo` means those are being made as the `root` user (even if you are signed in as alavaros). So, when you try to `laravel new update`, your user alavaros is trying to write to a directory that alavaros does not have permission to write to. **Using sudo to install things is not a bad thing.** You just need to learn how and when to adjust permissions, because they affect security. A better solution would be to use [homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/homestead).